# How to show laravel posts in styling columns

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working with laravel 5.5 and image below is how my posts are going to be shown.

[image: columns]

I know there is 2 ways to make this happen using `i+` or `offset query` here is my question?

1. Which way is the best approach for this depend on your personal experience?
2. How to make it happen?

PS: if any code required just tell me i'll update my question.

Thank you.

Comment: Is you question about Blade templating, Eloquent usage or something else?

Comment: is blade how to show my posts in different column orders as you see in image.